# How to get the n-th record from QSqlQuery in qt

Tags: qt, sqlite, record, qsqlquery

i try to get data from sqlite, I need to append the n-th and (n+1)-th row from the query to mylist (each item on the list contains n-th and (n+1)-th row) here is my code so far

```
 QSqlQuery query("SELECT country FROM artist");
 while(query.next()){
   m_datalist.append(new DataObject(query.value("country"),this_field _should_be_the_next_row_with_value contry));
 }
```

How do i get the n-th and (n+1)-th row from the query at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep the previous value in a variable:

```
QString previous = "";  // whatever the first one should be
while (query.next()) {
    QString nth = query.value(...);
    ...append(nth, previous);
    previous = nth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter variable:

```
int i=0;
while(query.next()){
   if(i==n || i==n+1)
    {
       m_datalist.append(...);
    }
    i++;
 }
```

or you can select only the records you need:

```
QSqlQuery query("SELECT country FROM artist LIMIT 2 OFFSET "+QString::number(n));
```